# sql oracle current month

Tags: sql, oracle

I was able to generate a query that would give me the auto saved for the month of October.

However, I'm trying to modify it so I can have a general one for the current month so I don't have to update the query every time.

Any ideas?

Below my query for October, 2015

```
SELECT
c.invoicenum,c.invoicedate, c.vendorname,c.account, c.invoiceid , decode(nvl(b.invoiceid,-1),-1,'No','Yes') "Approved",
decode(nvl(b.invoiceid,-1),-1,'No',nvl(a.invoiceid,-2),'No','Yes') "Auto Saved for Approval"
FROM 
(SELECT d.invoicenum,d.invoicedate, v.vendorname,d.account, d.invoiceid FROM invoice d, vendor v
WHERE d.invoicestatus in (1,5,7,8) AND v.vendorid=d.vendorid AND v.status=0 AND to_char(d.dateentered,'MMYY')='1015') c, 

(SELECT d.invoicenum,d.invoicedate, v.vendorname,d.account, d.invoiceid FROM invoice d, vendor v
WHERE d.invoicestatus in (7,8) AND v.vendorid=d.vendorid AND v.status=0 AND to_char(d.dateentered,'MMYY')='1015') b, 

(SELECT d.invoicenum,d.invoicedate, v.vendorname,d.account, d.invoiceid FROM invoicehistory b, invoice d, vendor v 
WHERE operationtype=21 AND d.invoicestatus in (7,8) AND b.invoiceid =d.invoiceid AND to_char(d.dateentered,'MMYY')='1015' AND v.vendorid=d.vendorid and v.status=0) a 

WHERE c.invoiceid=b.invoiceid and c.invoiceid=a.invoiceid(+) and a.invoiceid is null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to replace

```
to_char(d.dateentered,'MMYY')='1015'
```

with

```
trunc( d.dateEntered, 'MM' ) = trunc( sysdate, 'MM' )
```

`sysdate` returns the current date.  `trunc(<<date>>, 'MM')` returns midnight on the first of the month of the given input.

Comment: any difference between use `to_char` vs `trunc` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - If your intention is to compare dates, my bias is always to compare date expressions rather than comparing strings.  Particularly strings with 2-digit years.  `trunc(<<date>>,'MM')` is going to be slightly more efficient than `to_char(<<date>>,'MMYY')`  though at the point that is an important concern you'd probably be building a function-based index or changing the expression to be a `between` anyway.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave and  JuanCarlosOropeza . I really appreciate your attention and time to help me. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

change

```
AND to_char(d.dateentered,'MMYY') ='1015'
```

For

```
AND to_char(d.dateentered,'MMYY') =  to_char(SYSDATE,'MMYY')
```